# How to handle NULL in Where?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in `postgresql` which generates:

```
statusid,qty
17        25
          30
17        45
18        20
```

I want to remove all rows that `statuis` is `deleted` (`17`) and keep rows with `NULL`.
What I did is:

```
WHERE statuid not in (select statusid from statuses where statusname='deleted')
```

What I expected is:

```
statusid,qty
          30
18        20
```

but what I got is:

```
statusid,qty
18        20
```

is there another operator can can get this deisered result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare `NULL` with any value(`NOT IN` compares it), you have to use `IS NULL`:

```
WHERE statusid IS NULL OR  statusid not in (select statusid from statuses where statusname='deleted')
```

`NULL` is neither equal nor unequal to any other value not even with `NULL`. It's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Add `is null` explicitly:

```
<your query> or statuid is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
WHERE statusId IS NULL OR statusId NOT IN ( .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Null does't support any comparison :)
so, you need to write explicit code for it

```
WHERE statusid not in (select statusid from statuses where statusname='deleted') 
      or statusid is null;
```

or, more compact:

```
WHERE coalesce(statusid,0) not in (select statusid from statuses where statusname='deleted');
```

Comment: You need to exclude the `null` values from the sub-select as well, otherwise the `not in` won't work either (`from statuses st where st.statusname='deleted' and st.statusid is not null`)

Comment: yes, but a lookup table should not have a null as id... Although the OP should not have statusid null in the facts table :))

Comment: statusid is  FK... it can be null. I didn't show the whole query/tables.